# обработка сигналов oc в qt

Tags: linux, qt, posix

здравствуйте, необходимо обрабатывать системные сигналы posix, например sighup... я нашел мануал http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html , сделал все как там, да, все работает, только я не могу понять что там происходит, зачем так парные сокеты создаются, сначала вызывается hupSignalHandler(int), потом handleSigHup, вызываются системные вызовы write, read
если сделать так то сигналы тоже ловятся:

```
struct sigaction hup;

//hup.sa_handler = CAuth::hupSignalHandler;
::sigemptyset(&hup.sa_mask);
hup.sa_flags = 0;
hup.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;
hup.sa_sigaction = [](int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *){
    pid_t sender_pid = siginfo->si_pid;   //правда выводится тут -1
    qDebug() << "signal SIGINT was send by process with pid: " << static_cast<int>(sender_pid);
};

if (::sigaction(SIGHUP, &hup, 0))
   return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1.**

В простейшем случае можно использовать си-шный интерфейс, описанный в `<csignal>`:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <csignal>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto sig_handler = [](int sigcode)
                       {
                           qDebug() << QString("signal %1 was send").arg(sigcode);
                           qApp->exit(sigcode);
                       };

    ::signal(SIGHUP,  sig_handler);
    ::signal(SIGINT,  sig_handler);

    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Вариант 2.**

Если вы хотите выполнять некоторую более сложную обработку, можно доработать предыдущий способ.

Например, определить объект-обработчик и предоставить к нему глобальную точку доступа:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <csignal>

class SigHandler
{
public:
    void onSigInt()
    {
        qDebug() << QString("SIGINT signal was send");
    }

    void onSigHup()                                                                                                                                                             
    {                                                                                                                                                                           
        qDebug() << QString("SIGHUP signal was send");                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                           
};                                                                                                                                                                              

SigHandler*& sighandlerInstance()                                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                                               
    static SigHandler* globalInstance = nullptr;                                                                                                                                
    return globalInstance;                                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                                               

int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                                                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                                                               
    auto sig_handler_func = [](int sigcode)                                                                                                                                     
                            {                                                                                                                                                   
                                SigHandler* handler = ::sighandlerInstance();                                                                                                   
                                if (handler != nullptr)                                                                                                                         
                                {                                                                                                                                               
                                    switch (sigcode)                                                                                                                            
                                    {                                                                                                                                           
                                        case SIGINT:                                                                                                                            
                                            handler->onSigInt();                                                                                                                
                                            break;                                                                                                                              
                                        case SIGHUP:                                                                                                                            
                                            handler->onSigHup();                                                                                                                
                                            break;                                                                                                                              
                                        default:                                                                                                                                
                                            return;                                                                                                                             
                                    }                                                                                                                                           
                                    qApp->exit(sigcode);                                                                                                                        
                                }                                                                                                                                               
                            };                                                                                                                                                  

    SigHandler h;                                                                                                                                                               
    ::sighandlerInstance() = &h;                                                                                                                                                

    ::signal(SIGHUP, sig_handler_func);                                                                                                                                         
    ::signal(SIGINT, sig_handler_func);                                                                                                                                         

    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);                                                                                                                                           

    return app.exec();                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Comment: ну это понятно, только зачем там такой замес используется с созданием парных сокетов?

Comment: Разбираться в "замесе из сокетов" нет никакого желания. Приведённого мною выше решения лично мне хватает в большинстве случаев. Определитесь, что вы хотите делать в обработчике сигналов? Может быть простого решения будет достаточно, и не стоит зря усложнять код?

Comment: ну мне оно не подходит т.к. в зависимости от пришедших сигналов надо делать перезапуск или graceful stop у приложения(т.е. все обработчики должны быть "внутри" приложения)

Comment: Дополнил ответ в связи с вашим комментарием.

Comment: спасибо, но это кажись опять не то... мне, например, нужно при определенном сигнале закрыть все соединения сетевые, перечитать конфиг. файл, и т.д. ну в общем не прокатит вашим способом